# elisp function to insert signature at point or at end, according to the prefix parameter

Tags: message-mode

Under GNU Emacs 24.4.1, in Message Mode, C-c C-w runs `message-insert-signature`, which inserts the file `message-signature-file` at the end of the buffer, if such a signature is not already present.

How can I extend the function `message-insert-signature` so that to maintain its current functionalities but add one such that, when prefixing the command with C-u (which gives C-u C-c C-w), the signature is rather inserted at point (e.g. for mails where there are attachments which I wish to be AFTER the signature)?

It would be easy to define a function to insert `"\n-- \n"` and perform `(insert-file-contents signature-file)` at point, and to bind it to a new key combination, but my muscle memory is set to `C-u C-c C-w` from my previous use of VM, and I thought it could be the same for other users.

---

EDIT:

The code of the function `message-insert-signature`  bound by default to `C-c C-w` is interactive with parameters `(&optional force)`, which suggests that one could "force" the signature to be inserted, but I don't understand how the `(interactive (list 0))` works:

```
(defun message-insert-signature (&optional force)
  "Insert a signature.  See documentation for variable `message-signature'."
  (interactive (list 0))
  (let* ((signature
      (cond
       ((and (null message-signature)
         (eq force 0))
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (point-max))
          (not (re-search-backward message-signature-separator nil t))))
       ((and (null message-signature)
         force)
        t)
       ((functionp message-signature)
        (funcall message-signature))
       ((listp message-signature)
        (eval message-signature))
       (t message-signature)))
     signature-file)
    (setq signature
      (cond ((stringp signature)
         signature)
        ((and (eq t signature) message-signature-file)
         (setq signature-file
               (if (and message-signature-directory
                ;; don't actually use the signature directory
                ;; if message-signature-file contains a path.
                (not (file-name-directory
                      message-signature-file)))
               (expand-file-name message-signature-file
                         message-signature-directory)
             message-signature-file))
         (file-exists-p signature-file))))
    (when signature
      (goto-char (point-max))
      ;; Insert the signature.
      (unless (bolp)
    (insert "\n"))
      (when message-signature-insert-empty-line
    (insert "\n"))
      (insert "-- \n")
      (if (eq signature t)
      (insert-file-contents signature-file)
    (insert signature))
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (or (bolp) (insert "\n")))))
```

Comment: From what I understand, your question is more about how to bind something to the C-u prefix, rather than how to write the actual function. Is that correct?

Comment: It is my understanding that the C-u prefix to any short cut X calling function F should be "caught" by the function F, hence the question?

Comment: Yes. I mean that your question is saying *"I know how to insert signature. How can I capture C-u in a function"*. Meanwhile, your title is asking *"how do I insert signature"*. You should change the title to match the question.

Comment: Agreed: made the title more explicit.

Answer (score 5):

What you need to do is write a new interactive function that receives the optional [prefix argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html) and runs either the "insert here" or "insert at bottom" functions.  For your function to receive the prefix, it needs to have `(interactive "P")`.  A single `C-u` prefix will be received as the list `(4)`.  Below is the general sort of thing you have to do.

```el
(defun my/insert-signature (&optional arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (if (equal arg '(4))
      (progn
        (insert "\n--\n")
        (insert-file-contents mail-signature-file))
    (message-insert-signature)))
```

Comment: Instead of `(equal arg '(4))` it's best to just use `arg` itself. This way it will also work with numeric prefixes (which might be more convenient to time depending on the keybind).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, based on the original function called by `C-c C-w` in message mode, `message-insert-signature`, and on @erikstokes's answer and @malabarba's comment, followed by the instruction to bind it to `C-c C-w`.

It works as I wished: it inserts the signature at the end of the email via `C-c C-w`, and at point when called via `C-u C-c C-w`. As the original function, it *does not* insert the signature if one is already present in the email.

```
(defun jyby/insert-signature (&optional arg)
  "Insert a signature.
  If prefixed with C-u, inserts it at point,
  otherwise inserts it at the end of the buffer."
  (interactive "P")
  (let* ((signature
      (cond
       ((null message-signature)     
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (point-max))
          (not (re-search-backward message-signature-separator nil t))))
       ((null message-signature) t)
       ((functionp message-signature)
        (funcall message-signature))
       ((listp message-signature)
        (eval message-signature))
       (t message-signature)))
     signature-file)
    (setq signature
      (cond ((stringp signature)
         signature)
        ((and (eq t signature) message-signature-file)
         (setq signature-file
               (if (and message-signature-directory
                ;; don't actually use the signature directory
                ;; if message-signature-file contains a path.
                (not (file-name-directory
                      message-signature-file)))
               (expand-file-name message-signature-file
                         message-signature-directory)
             message-signature-file))
         (file-exists-p signature-file))))
    (when signature 
     (save-excursion
      (if (not arg)
        (goto-char (point-max))
      )
      ;; Insert the signature.
      (unless (bolp)
    (insert "\n"))
      (when message-signature-insert-empty-line
    (insert "\n"))
      (insert "-- \n")
      (if (eq signature t)
      (insert-file-contents signature-file)
    (insert signature))
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (or (bolp) (insert "\n"))))))

(local-unset-key (kbd "C-c C-w"))  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-w") 'jyby/insert-signature)
```

I might modify it later so that it ignores existing signatures when called with a prefix.